# JSON.parse(data) Object.keys email how can i do? eval("aaa@gmail.com") not work records.accounts.["aaa@gmail.com"] not work

Tags: javascript, json

```js
// JSON that I have
const data = `{
    "accounts": {
        "aaa@gmail.com": {
            "zipcode": "",
            "inCharge": ""
       },
        "bbb@gmail.com": {
            "zipcode": "",
            "inCharge": ""
       },
        "ccc@gmail.com": {
            "zipcode": "",
            "inCharge": ""
       }
    }
}`

const records = JSON.parse(data);
const columns = Object.keys(records.accounts.aaa@gmail.com);
```

I have tried the following, none of which did work:

```js
records.accounts.aaa@gmail.com records.accounts.["aaa@gmail.com"]
records.accounts.eval("aaa@gmail.com")
```

Comment: Please be more precise with what you are trying to achieve? It's not clear at all. Verify the validity of the email address?(-> use RegEx) Loop through all the emails? (-> use `Object.keys(data.accounts)` or `Object.entries(data.accounts)`) Or just access the value using the email address? (-> use `records.accounts["aaa@gmail.com"]`)

Comment: Object.keys(records.accounts.["aaa@gmail.com"]) -->
get "zipcode","inCharge" --> read this column make sql table i want but can't access object.object.object --> records.accounts.["aaa@gmail.com"]  --> aaa@gmail.com can't get object

Answer (score -1):

You can access it using array accessor

```js
const data = {
    "accounts": {
        "aaa@gmail.com": {
            "zipcode": "",
            "inCharge": ""
       },
        "bbb@gmail.com": {
            "zipcode": "",
            "inCharge": ""
       },
        "ccc@gmail.com": {
            "zipcode": "",
            "inCharge": ""
       }
    }
}

console.log(data.accounts["aaa@gmail.com"])
```